# AHK IF statement

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

```
ArrayCount = 0
Loop, Read, Times.txt   ; This loop retrieves each line from the file.
{
    ArrayCount += 1  ; Keep track of how many items are in the array.
    ArrayTime%ArrayCount% := A_LoopReadLine  
}

WinGetTitle, Title, A
Loop %ArrayCount%
{
 element := ArrayTime%A_Index%
 Time = %A_WDay%%A_Hour%%A_Min%
 msgbox %Time% , %element%
 if (Time=%element%)
 {
  IfWinExist, Test.txt
  {
   WinActivate
    Sleep 500
    Send Hi{enter}
    msgbox %Time% , %element%
    Sleep 500
    WinActivate, %Title%
  }
 }
}
```

Ok so the main issue is with this part:

if (Time=%element%)

I have also tried

if (%Time%=%element%)

if (A_WDay . A_Hour . A_Min=%element%)

And I think some other similar variations, the problem I'm getting is it's either always true, or always false, depending on how I have it written.
Inside the text file is a list like this:

10000

10700

11400

20400

21100

I add an extra line that has the current time for testing, and I added the msgbox to compare, and I can clearly see they're both the same when it doesn't work, or that they're different when it does. Sorry for such a basic question but I feel like I've really been trying for a long time and read everything I can on variables and IF statements, thanks for any help.

Also the point of it is I need it to go off every 7 hours starting at midnight on sunday, this is what I came up with, if there's maybe a completely better way in general I'd be happy to hear that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if % Time = element
{
    MsgBox, Equal!
}
```

As for the scheduling part, try running your script through Windows Task Scheduler (hit `Windows+R`, type `taskschd.msc` and press Enter). There are tutorials on the Internet explaining how to create new tasks.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to timers, have a look at this as an example.

```
SetTimer, AlertType1, 60000
ToAlertType1:=1
ToAlertType2:=1

AlertType1:
;If A_WDay between 2 and 7              ; is day monday - sunday?
;{
If (A_Hour = 7 or A_Hour = 13)
{
    If (ToAlertType1)
    {
        SoundBeep, 500, 500
        ToAlertType2:=1
        ToAlertType1:=0
        MsgBox, 4096,%AppName%, Msg1.
        Return
    }
}
Else if (A_Hour = 21)
{
    If (ToAlertType2)
    {
        SoundBeep, 500, 500
        ToAlertType2:=0
        ToAlertType1:=1
        MsgBox, 4096,%AppName%, Msg2.
        Return
    }
}
;}
Return
```